# java compile "( expected" error

Tags: java

I use bluej.
https://gyazo.com/77463830f2b557c86fbf65c7401053a4

i don't find where do I miss "("

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year){
    if checkDate(day,month,year)=false {
        _day=default_Day;
        _month=default_Month; 
        _year=default_Year;}
    else {
        _day=day;
        _month=month;
        _year=year;
    }
```

thanks in advance=)

Comment: In java, the condition you are checking "if" needs to be enclosed in parentheses "()", `if ( checkDate(day,month,year)=false )`

Comment: The expression for `if` must be surrounded by parens: `if (checkDate...)`. Also, the `=` in `=false` must be `==` -- you're checking equality, not assigning a value. You should read the [Java nuts and bolts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) tutorial, as it will give you a good primer on Java syntax.

Comment: As a matter of style, you would not compare to `false`. Instead you would use the `!` operator: `if (!checkDate(day,month,year)) {`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the condition in parenthesis and perform the comparison using `==` operator (`=`) is an assignment operator. So,

Change

```
if checkDate(day,month,year)=false{
```

to

```
if (checkDate(day,month,year) == false){
```

Or, to make it simpler, change it to

```
if (!checkDate(day,month,year)){
```

Answer (score 0):

In second line of your code both '(' and ')' are missing. 
Moreover you mistake '=' (assigns) with '==' (equals).
Besides

```
if (checkDate(day,month,year)==false)
```

can be expressed simpler as

```
if (!checkDate(day,month,year))




     public Date(int day, int month, int year){
            if (checkDate(day,month,year)==false) {
//if (!checkDate(day,month,year)) { <- exactly the same, but simpler
                _day=default_Day;
                _month=default_Month; 
                _year=default_Year;
        }
            else {
                _day=day;
                _month=month;
                _year=year;
            }
```